# Is is possible to use concat_idents! to acess struct fields?

Tags: rust, macros

Is it possible some way to manipulate idents to access similarly named struct fields?

I have 2 structs like this:

```rust
struct Fridge {
    tomatos: HashMap<TomatoId, Tomato>,
    oranges: HashMap<TomatoId, Orange>,

    // and many more other similar cases
}
```

```rust
struct List {
    tomato: TomatoId,
    orange: OrangeId,

    // and so on
}
```

That are part of a larger application, where one holds indices to access the other.

I wanted to check similarly named fields with a macro like this:

```rust
macro_rules! check_ref {
    ($s:ident, $ref_src:ident, $ref_name:ident) => {
        check_ref!($s, concat_idents!($ref_name, s), $ref_src.$ref_name, stringify!($refname))
    };

    ($source:ident, $subfield:expr, $ref_src:expr, $error_str:expr) => {
        $source
            .$subfield
            .get(&($ref_src))
            .map(|_| ())
            .ok_or_else(|| {
                error!("no such {}: {}", , $error_str);
                ()
            })
    }
}
```

Is it possible at all? (maybe procmacro?)

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c7c06afaa4a576b1ff42bc6b25f5c45) (not compiling)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible at all to build a field name with `concat_idents!()` and use that to access a field of a struct.

Macros can only be invoked in item, statement, pattern or expression position. The field identifier in `my_struct.my_field` is neither of these, so you can't replace it with a macro invocation. recursive macro calls like you used won't help. The return value of a macro invocation will never become a lone identifier, but can only be one of the things listed above.

This can't be implemented as a declarative macro. It's possible to implement this as a proc macro, but an easier approach is using the [`paste` crate](https://docs.rs/paste/latest/paste/).